# How to add TR on the top of the Table in this case?

Tags: jquery, dom

I got a list of string returned from ajax and I need to queue on the top a a table(html). By using append it adds to the bottom. I found this solution as commented in the line but I have no clue how to proceed selecting by the ID (#..)

```
for (i = 0; i < msg.WrittenList.length; i++)
{
    $("#tbWritten").append("<tr><td>" + msg.WrittenList[i] + "</td></tr>");
    // $('table > tbody > tr:first').before('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>');     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use jQuery's [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), which works like `append()` but before the rest of the content.

```
$("#tbWritten").prepend("<tr><td>" + msg.WrittenList[i] + "</td></tr>");
```